# Find out which property changed on ListChangedEvent in C#

Tags: c#, properties, bindinglist

I have BindingList and have event attached to it:

```
    public void OnListChangedEvent(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
        {

        }
        else
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
        {
        }
        else
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
        {
        };
    }
```

Now, how to find out which property value changed if change type is "ListChangedType.ItemChanged"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424554/why-does-bindingsource-not-tell-me-which-property-has-changed

Answer (score 2):

It should be found via `e.PropertyDescriptor`